# When does the train from Encarnación to Posadas run?

Tags: trains, argentina, paraguay

There is an international train that between Encarnacion, Paraguay to Posadas, Argentina. Found a mention of it in a guidebook and it has it's own page at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posadas-Encarnaci%C3%B3n_International_Train).

**Which days and times does it run?**

My guidebook says to go on weekdays and not on Saturday but no mention of Sunday. Wikipedia has a mention that the ride takes 8 mins but nothing about when. The wikivoyage page on Posadas says it is no longer running but their page on Encarnacion says that it does with approximate times but not days.

Comment: "Weekdays not Saturdays" is standard phrasing in train timetables for "Monday through Friday only". The phrasing needs to exclude Saturday explicitly because "weekday" traditionally means Monday through Saturday.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Where in the world does weekday include Saturday?

Comment: @gerrit: In train timetables. I suppose it is an UIC convention, but everything UIC is behind insanely high paywalls, so I cannot reference that.

Comment: @gerrit: Parking zones in Germany often require parking tickets for time periods described as something like "weekdays, 8-19h". Without further specification, that does also include Saturday. So it's a good idea to make this explicit.

Comment: @helm Does that mean that if a glass container can only be used *Werktage 9-12 15-18" that I can use it on a Saturday?

Comment: @gerrit Should be the case, yes. I only looked it up for parking because I wasn't sure there myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a page about this service on the Argentinian government website](https://www.argentina.gob.ar/transporte/trenes-argentinos/horarios-tarifas-y-recorridos/servicios-regionales-larga-distancia/posadas-encarnacion). All the information is in an [image](https://www.argentina.gob.ar/sites/default/files/posadas_-_encarnacion_2019-05-21_web.jpg) (accessibility? what's that?). The image is dated 21/05/2019.

The service operates from Monday to Friday. (There is no mention of public holidays, but you should double-check if you travel on a day that's a holiday in either country.) Trains depart every 30 min all day: from Posadas from 07:15 to 18:15,  from Encarnación from 07:30 to 18:30. The trip takes 8 minutes. The fare since 02/02/2019 is AR$56 or ₲12000.

The page mentions that you need to have your passport (presumably with applicable visa) or identity card (presumably for Paraguayans and Argentinians only). There is additional information for minors (you may need to show that you have the proper vaccinations and that your parents authorized the trip). If you pass the border with products purchased in the other country, you need to go through customs (*sector de Aduanas*).

If the service is suspended or modified, hopefully there would be a mention on [the service modifications page](https://www.argentina.gob.ar/transporte/trenes-argentinos/modificaciones-en-el-servicio).

Please note that I have no local knowledge and am just reporting what I found on the web.